# Menu, HTML5, CSS, Panel, Slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already tried to find an answer for this but can't seem to find it... i want to do something like this

http://es.wix.com/website-template/view/html/748?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fes.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F4&bookName=create-master-b-test&galleryDocIndex=4

So, far I got the menu which is working with css3, html and java..... but I can't put this one

http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html

with the menu working together... they won't do ...

This is my website http://www.softglobal.com.mx you can see the menu there... I want to understand how the sliding panels work. so I can do it myself. what am I doing wrong??  I really want to learn and understand how it work in the example and do it myself. Thank you.

Comment: Hey , why don't you see the source of that website . :)

Comment: I did, but I don't understand all of it... do you think you can help me? besides I want to learn how's it done.